# Text-to-speech when button is clicked in html with help of java in playframework

Tags: jquery, text-to-speech, playframework-2.1, voice

I am playing with Application Developer. 
I need my page to speak a sentence according to my argument. 
For example if I pass "Hello word" and press a button in html it should say "Hello word". 
How can I use  java with speech api (or other any api in java which helps me do text-to-speech) and it should be passed to html (View) through ajax. 
Please help me with sample code.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a service like this https://www.mashape.com/voicerss/text-to-speech-1#!documentation